# how to separate languages from currencies using vu-i18n

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, internationalization, vue-i18n

I'm trying to let the user have the ability to change the display language and currency independently, I'm using the [Vue-I18n](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/) v9 plugin on Vue3+Vite project. The project needs to support more than 20 languages and more than 25 currencies, until now I couldn't find a clear way to do it, the closest thing I could think of is to make multiple number formatting rules for each language-currency combination like so :

**localize/currencies.js**

```js
export default {
  'en-US': {
    currency: {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD",
      ...
    }
  },
  'ru-US': {
    currency: {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

then add it as `numberFormats` option of Vue-I18n's `createI18n` function like so

**localize/index.js**

```js
import numberFormats from "./currencies.js";

export default createI18n({
  ...
  numberFormats,
  ...
})
```

this would work however this means that I've got to make about 500 entries for each language-currency(country) combination, which makes me smile just by thinking of it :). also this won't work if I wanted to use two letter identifiers like `en` instead of `en-US`, using a two letter approach makes more sense for my use case as browsers only show the languages preference and related country from [`navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language) property, so I doubt that I'll see something like `ar-CA` Arabic language with Canadian Dollar.

so is there any recommended way? I'm new to I18n and the internationalization problems in general it's my first time.

Answer (score 0):

Vue-I18n has a function [`setNumberFormat`](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/api/#setnumberformat-locale-format) which you should use. That will separate the currency entirely from the localizations and you can change it whenever. You don’t need to make any combinations or misuse the country code as currency indicator.

Comment: I'm using v9 of the plugin but the problem is still the same, the `setNumberFormat` in v8 is like what I'm doing where the first argument is (locale) 'en-US' and the second one is the format. so it binds the format to that specific locale, where I want a way to be independent of the locale. you're right about misusing the country code, but I don't know how else to do it unless I make my own custom identifiers.

Comment: @anasali I use this in production, both v8 and v9. Only en, fi, de, etc as locale and set number formats based on user selection. It works just fine.